# Bot twitter stopped working

Tags: javascript, json, twitter

So I'm working on a bot for twitter that replies to people who say 'notice me senpai' it was working flawlessly until I modified something in my code , and I can't figure out what caused this... I'm fairly new to javascript we started learning it a few days ago at my school and I thought it'd be cool to get better at it by creating a bot for twitter , but I'm kind of lost to say the least.

```
    var Twitter = require('twitter');
    var keys = require('./keysBot.json');
```

`var client = new Twitter(keys);


var word = 'Notice me senpai';

var id_str, screen_name;


client.stream('statuses/filter', {track: word}, function(stream) {
  console.log('Bot started looking for the word ' + word + '.');
  stream.on('data', function(tweet) {


   if(word == 'Notice me senpai') { 

        console.log(tweet.text);
        id_str = tweet.id_str;
        screen_name = tweet.user.screen_name;


        client.post('statuses/update', {in_reply_to_status_id: id_str,
        status: '@' + screen_name + ' Hello Kōhai-kun!'},
        function(error, tweet, response){
            if(error) throw error;
            console.log(tweet);  
        });
    }
   })

  stream.on('error', function(error) {
    throw error;
  });
});`

I don't really know how the formatting works on this website , so i'm sorry if it looks ugly.

Comment: what did you modify? Surely that is where you should start looking for your error?

Comment: I don't really remember , that sounds stupid I know  but I rushed it a bit , I tried coding everything again but it didn't work. The error appears when the bot detects someone's tweet....

Comment: So what error are you actually getting? Can you show us some output?

Comment: Sure! I get something like this

 C:\Users\Rozalina\npm_demo>node bot.js
Bot started looking for the word Notice me senpai.
DOES BTS SHARE A DORM WITH THEIR MANAGER OR NOT?! NOTICE ME SENPAI! �

C:\Users\Rozalina\npm_demo\bot.js:30
            if(error) throw error;
                      ^
[object Object]

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after trying to find what caused this I logged in to apps.twitter.com and found out that my app was restricted from performing write action so I then contacted twitter and explained how my bot works ,and they unlocked my bot and now it's working flawlessly again ! :)